# How can I "zoom out" while viewing a text file on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, display, settings, text

On my new iPhone 4, plain text files display at a width of 38 columns. Rows with more than 38 characters are wrapped. I want to view text files containing prose formatted with widths of 70 or 80 characters. This would mean either shrinking the display (I imagine it would still be readable under landscape orientation) or disabling word-wrap. Is there a way to do either?

Comment: Which application are you using to view plain text?

Comment: I've tried Dropbox and Safari. Both render text files the same way.